# CSS Gradient 124deg rainbow border moving

Tags: css

I found the following CSS script to create rainbow moving background.

```
a.logolayout {
    background: linear-gradient(124deg, rgba(255,26,0,0.65), rgba(232,29,29,0.65), rgba(232,183,29,0.65), rgba(227,232,29,0.65), rgba(29,232, 64,0.65), rgba(29,221,232,0.65), rgba(43,29,232,0.65), rgba(221,0,243,0.65), rgba(221,0,243,0.65));
    transition: 0.8s;
    border: 1px; solid none;
    -webkit-animation: rainbow 19s ease infinite;
    -z-animation: rainbow 19s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: rainbow 19s ease infinite;
    animation: rainbow 19s ease infinite;
    background-size: 200% 200%;
}

a.logolayout:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(124deg, rgba(255,26,0,0.85), rgba(232,29,29,0.85), rgba(232,183,29,0.85), rgba(227,232,29,0.85), rgba(29,232, 64,0.85), rgba(29,221,232,0.85), rgba(43,29,232,0.85),      rgba(221,0,243,0.85), rgba(221,0,243,0.85));
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    color: white;
    -webkit-animation: rainbow 9s ease infinite;
    -z-animation: rainbow 9s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: rainbow 9s ease infinite;
    animation: rainbow 9s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-o-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
```

Is it possible just to have a border that is doing the same thing?

```
|---------|
|  text   |
|---------|
```

The text has no background and is transparent. Only the border has the rainbow effect. The lines are the border and have a border-width like 5px.

**Update:**

```
<div id="full-background-pic">
    <a class="only-rainbow-border-moving" > text-see the backgroundpic</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a php developer not CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this then?

```css
a.logolayout {
    background: linear-gradient(124deg, rgba(255,26,0,0.65), rgba(232,29,29,0.65), rgba(232,183,29,0.65), rgba(227,232,29,0.65), rgba(29,232, 64,0.65), rgba(29,221,232,0.65), rgba(43,29,232,0.65), rgba(221,0,243,0.65), rgba(221,0,243,0.65));
    transition: 0.8s;
    border: 1px; solid none;
    -webkit-animation: rainbow 9s ease infinite;
    -z-animation: rainbow 9s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: rainbow 9s ease infinite;
    animation: rainbow 9s ease infinite;
    background-size: 200% 200%;
}

a.logolayout:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(124deg, rgba(255,26,0,0.85), rgba(232,29,29,0.85), rgba(232,183,29,0.85), rgba(227,232,29,0.85), rgba(29,232, 64,0.85), rgba(29,221,232,0.85), rgba(43,29,232,0.85),      rgba(221,0,243,0.85), rgba(221,0,243,0.85));
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    -webkit-animation: rainbow 5s ease infinite;
    -z-animation: rainbow 5s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: rainbow 5s ease infinite;
    animation: rainbow 5s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-o-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}

a.logolayout{
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block
}

a.logolayout div{
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.bgimg{
  padding 20px;
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg);
}

.innerbgimg{
  background: -5px -5px url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimg">
<a class="logolayout">
<div class="innerbgimg">Test</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Not really. I did an update to make it more clear.

Comment: Hey, thanks again, no not really. Like I asked. I really want to have instead of a background this as a border. Is it possible in CSS?

Comment: if you want a truly transparent background with gradient border, then its currently not possible. what you can do is a **hack** like what I did in the answer by emulating the *border* and and making the background the same as its parent background so that it looks *transparent*